# C++ Reading a file Char by Char into String; Crashes

Tags: c++, string, char

When I am reading a text file one character at a time then sending that character to a string (which is an array of characters) it seems to work and the output shows correctly'ish but then it crashes. Why?

secondary question: It doesn't appear to add white spaces to the string (which is an array of characters). Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int SIZE = 0;

    char text;  
    string textArray;

    fstream inFile("text.txt"); //opens text.txt

    //checks if file was opened
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Error opening the file.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    //reads each character then adds the character to the array
    while (inFile >> text)
    {
        //if you coment out line 46 and 47 the program wont crash
        textArray[SIZE] = text; //comment out // doesnt add white spaces 
        cout << textArray[SIZE]; //comment out // the output form this is the text.txt but no white spaces
        SIZE++;
    }
    inFile.close(); //closes text.txt

    cout << SIZE; //output the size of the array

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting characters in your string using `[]` that do not exist because your string is created with *zero* length. Use `push_back()`

Comment: Thanks, that is something to do with vectors? I am aware of vectors but this is a beginner class and vectors are not covered. Is there anyway to do this without vectors?

Comment: Its the same with `std::vector` as `std::string`. You should find a tutorial or better still get a good book and work through that.

Comment: You can also use: `textArray += text;` to append characters to the end of the string

Comment: @Galik - Nice! Now how about them white spaces (or blank spaces) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I am reading a text file one character at a time then sending that character to a string (which is an array of characters) it seems to work and the output shows correctly'ish but then it crashes. Why?

The reason it works correctly for you now is because of luck. The default constructed

```
string textArray;
```

is empty. The implementation may reserve some space for characters to be input, but it does not have to do this. If you want to push characters onto the end of this string for each character you read from the stream, you can do something like this:

```
while (inFile >> text)
{
    cout << text;
    textArray += text;
}
```

Then to output the size of the string, use:

```
cout << textArray.size();
```

> It doesn't appear to add white spaces to the string (which is an array of characters). Why?

This is because of the way that C++ streams read text. When an input stream reads in a character or string via

```
myInputStream >> myChar;
```

or

```
myInputStream >> myString;
```

it may skip any leading whitespace before it gives you the character or string you get. This is controlled by the stream flag `std::ios_base::skipws`. To disable this behaviour, call:

```
inFile.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);
// OR
inFile >> std::noskipws;
```

To reenable this behaviour, call:

```
inFile.setf(std::ios_base::skipws);
// OR
inFile >> std::skipws;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
textArray[SIZE] = text;
```

It is undefined behavior to write into the location `SIZE` when the size of the string is less than or equal to `SIZE`.

One correct way to append a character is:

```
textArray.push_back(text);
```

You do not need the `SIZE` variable at all.  The size of the string can be obtained from `textArray.size()`.

Comment: Why not just `textArray += text` ?

Comment: @Tas The operations are completely equivalent.

Comment: @Tas There's more than one way to skin this cat: `push_back`, `append`, `operator+=`, and `operator+`. It's really a matter of taste here.

Answer (score 0):

> it crashes. Why?

You try to access addresses that are not part of the string yet:

```
textArray[SIZE] = text;      SIZE++;
```

You can use `std::string.push_back(char c)`

> It doesn't appear to add white spaces to the string (which is an array of characters). Why?

Try:

```
fStreamVar >> std::noskipws;
```

right after you open the file.

Comment: If I am interpreting you correctly the output is skipping white spaces. They are, however, in fact actually there in the string? I tried adding it right after opening the file but it gave me the error:  [Error] qualified-id in declaration before ';' token

Comment: I think it wasn't clear that this is for actual fstream variable. Try it now.

Comment: Yep I figured that so I put it in my while loop and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone from all the replys the following was the solutions I was looking for.

```
while (inFile >> std::noskipws >> text)
```

and

```
textArray += text;
```

I understand now why it was doing what it was doing. Thanks so much! My problem was I had just finished doing arrays with int and switching over to characters and strings was warping my brain.

Thanks all!